# Где взять информацию по PDO для работы с mySQL в PHP 5.2.X?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Хотелось бы на русском. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - Официальная документация. Хоть и не на русском, но все-равно ясно и понятно. :]

Comment: Почему это не на русском?) Вроде как уже перевели http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

[Почему следует использовать PDO для доступа к базам данных?](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=610).